# How does the rise in temperature of fuse wire depend upon its radius?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, temperature

The  question could be understood as if we have two fuse wires one of current rating 1 A and one of current rating 8A then what should be the ratio of their radius?

I tried the following:

We know, $Q = mc \Delta t$

but by Joule's law of heating, we also know that $H = I^2 R t$

Assuming that no heat is lost in the surroundings,

​we get $Q = H$

=>     $mc \Delta t = I^2 R t$

=>     $\Delta t = \frac{I^2 R t}{mc}$

But $m = V d = AL d$

and $R = \frac{\rho L}A$

=> $\Delta t = \frac{I^2 \rho t}{A^2 d}$

Here we come across a surprising reveal that the rise in temperature doesn't depend on the length of the fuse wires.

Moving ahead, assuming a wire of circular cross-section ( as they generally are),

$A = \pi * r^2$

=> $\Delta t = \frac{I^2 \rho t} {\pi^2 r^4 d}$

The temperature rise should be inversely proportional to the tesseract of radius, i.e. r to the fourth power, which essentially implies that  the ratio of the radius of two fuse wires one of current rating 1 A and one of current rating 8A should be *1:2*.

However, my science textbook not only says that it should be "1:4"  but also that the temperature rise should be inversely proportional to the cube of radius, i.e. r to the third power.

Who is correct, why and how?
Please don't consider it as a homework question. It does answer my homework question but the central idea is about the relation not my homework.

Comment: Could it be because the resistance depends on temperature?

Comment: Why is the 'surprising' reveal actually surprising? You would need more voltage to drive a given current through the wire, that is all.

Comment: @JonCuster Yeah yeah, my bad. It's completely off-topic anyways

Comment: @physicopath No idea tbh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple fuse models exist, with various levels of complexity. It's appealing to apply simplifying assumptions, until they fail to predict actual behavior.

(For example, ignoring the attachment points and axial heat transfer, as you did, allows the entire fuse wire to be idealized as rising to a uniform temperature. Thus, it shouldn't be surprising that length drops out as a relevant parameter, because you ignored heat transfer along the length! But, whoops, we always find that fuses fail in the middle, and this is an outcome of axial heat transfer resulting in the ends of the wire being cooler, where they're mounted to a thermal mass.)

You also ignored lateral heat transfer, which resulted in the present inconsistency of the temperature rise depending on $r^{-4}$ vs. some other dependency.

Let's instead consider lateral heat transfer to the surroundings, idealized via [Newton's law of cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling) (i.e., the heat flux scaling linearly with the temperature difference). The energy balance is now

$$\frac{I^2\rho L}{\pi r^2}-2\pi r h L(T-T_\infty)=\pi r^2 pc L\frac{dT}{dt}$$

(current $I$, resistivity $\rho$, length $L$, radius $r$, [heat transfer coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer_coefficient)  $h$, wire temperature $T$, ambient temperature $T_\infty$, density $p$ and time $t$). If the fuse doesn't blow very fast, and its thermal mass is small, we might ignore the thermal accumulation term and obtain

$$\Delta T=T-T_\infty=\frac{I^2\rho}{2\pi^2r^3h},$$

which provides the radius-cubed term I believe your text is referring to. This relation—that the current scales as $r^{3/2}$ for a given fuse material and geometry—is sometimes known as [Preece's equation](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspl.1883.0133), from a report published in 1883.

I'm not defending either model but merely showing how different dependencies can arise from various assumptions and idealizations.

More generally, we could write the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) as

$$k\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}+\frac{I^2\rho}{(\pi r^2)^2}-\frac{2[h(T-T_\infty)+\sigma\epsilon(T^4-T_\infty^4)]}{r}=pc\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$$

(thermal conductivity $k$, Stefan–Boltzmann constant $\sigma$, emissivity $\epsilon$, all material properties dependent on temperature.) for a long fuse wire that cools by convection, radiation, and conduction to its connected ends. Note that even this more complex model ignores lateral conduction within the wire! This equation would need to be solved numerically, providing improved predictive accuracy at the expense of losing simple scaling relations.

Comment: Okay, so it was the heat transfer that I was missing out on. Thanks, sir!